# Linear difference equation with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

> Given scalars $a_0,...,a_n$ with $a_0$ nonzero, and given a signal
>   $\{z_k\}$, the equation $a_0y_{k+n} +$
>   $a_1y_{k+n-1}+...+a_{n-1}y_{k+1}+a_ny_k=z_k$ is called a linear
>   difference equation (or linear recurrence relation) of order $n$. For
>   simplicity, $a_0$ is often taken equal to $1$. If $\{z_k\}$ is the
>   zero sequence, the equation is homogeneous; otherwise, the equation is
>   nonhomogeneous.

I'm confused by this notation. Why are all the a's subscript being incremented then something happens to them in the ellipses and then it is decremented by $n-1$ but even though it's decreasing from the subscript $n$, it reaches $a_n$ on the last part of the equation? Where are the subscript values of $k$ coming from? I was trying to look at the practical example (image attached below) and trying to piece out which value would map to which but I'm still very lost.

[image]

Comment: For example, in the case $n=2$ with $a_0 = 1$, $a_1 = 2$ and $a_2 = 3$ the difference equation would be $y_{k+2} + 2 y_{k+1} + 3 y_k = z_k$.

Comment: As for the example: Yes that should be enough. Another approach is to take a random vector and "project away" each basis vector.

Comment: Apart from that we really can't take responsibility of some other authors sloppiness.

Comment: lollll is this CTY

Comment: lin alg by david lay